# Hash extend by some funciton

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, extend

I have a object .

```
reqeuest ={"_command":".login","username":"rahul","password":"12345"}
```

i want to add

```
{'on':{
                login:function(){
                    console.log("logged in ");
                },
                error:function(){
                    console.log("oops error ");
                }
            }}
```

So it will become like it :

```
{
"_command":".login","username":"rahul","password":"12345",

'on':{
                login:function(){
                    console.log("logged in ");
                },
                error:function(){
                    console.log("oops error ");
                }
            }}
```

what i tried is

```
  request=$.extend(request,{'on':{
                login:function(){
                    console.log("logged in ");
                },
                error:function(){
                    console.log("oops error ");
                }
            }});
```

or

```
  hash.extend(request,{'on':{
            login:function(){
                console.log("logged in ");
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("oops error ");
            }
        }});
```

but it  is not doing the what required what should i do ?

Comment: What is the `hash.extend` function doing?

Comment: It also extend the hash i think it is same as $.extend  , i have one hash.js file in inclusion which has this funciton

Comment: What are you wanting it to do?

Comment: Is the `reqeuest` typo in your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do this:

```
request["on"] = {
    login:function(){
        console.log("logged in ");
    },
    error:function() {
        console.log("oops error ");
    }
};
```

To test it, go to Script tab in firebug, and write 'request' on the 'Watch' tab. It's working.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
request.on = {
    login: function() {
        console.log("logged in ");
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("oops error ");
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working . if i remove the function and put some value than it works

Comment: @Rahul: [Yes it is](http://jsfiddle.net/Eric/VJPAj/). You must be doing something else you're not showing us.